# How to guarantee two statements will execute sequentially without being interrupted by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In a simple Java program, I have two Threads running, `addSome` and `subtractSome`.

These two Threads are both working on the same `box` object. So essentially, they are both adding and subtracting items from this box, concurrently.

For the purpose of understanding threads and such, I am trying to output the content of the boxes and the Thread that is currently working.

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
System.out.println("Items: " + contents);
```

The problem is, I realized, because of the structure of the `if` statements in the `Box` class (you can only take items when there are items in the box etc) that the first output statement is printing **and then** switching to the other Thread where new contents are being added and then coming back to the first Thread where the old contents are being printed out.

Basically, I want to make sure that both those statements are executed at the same time by the same thread and nothing should happen in between.

Comment: acquire lock and process statements.

Comment: The simplest and most pragmatic solution would be to wrap the accesses into a `synchronized(box) { /* Do stuff here */ }` block, but without further details, it's hard to tell whether this is appropriate here.

Comment: You can't guarantee that they will execute sequentially, with nothing from another task in-between.  You *can*, however somehow lock access to the data so that only one thread accesses it at a time.  But carefully note that any lock is ultimately *cooperative* -- the other thread must use the same locking protocol.

Answer (score 3):

use synchronized concepts either **synchronized method** or **synchronized block**.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of Thread Synchronization

It uses of concept of acquiring locks which will allow you to achieve your objective